# Set a certain size for a DataMatrixCode.png, with Python(pylibdmxt)

Tags: python

Im working on a label generator(labels for products). Im able to create a 2D-Datamatrix code. But I dont know how to set a certain Siz for the created png. I think its not much of code. But i didn't find anything online.

```
 def createDatamatrix(self):

    
        data = data = 'SN: 1665464'+'\nTN: H76vdg/'+'\nConfigs:Sample'
        self.encoded_data = encode(data.encode('utf-8'))
        self.img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (self.encoded_data.width, 
        self.encoded_data.height), 
        self.encoded_data.pixels)
        self.img.save('test.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, Suggestions for improvement? :

```
def createDatamatrix(self):

    try:
        size = 12*mm
        data = data = 'SN: '+self.sn+'\nTN: '+self.tn+'\nConfigs: '+self.config
        encoder = dme(data)
        encoder.save(self.sn+'.png')
        self.img = Image(self.sn+'.png', width=size, height=size)
        

    except Exception:
        print("Error CreateDatamatrix")
```

Comment: Maybe someone knows a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a white picture and then paste the Datamatrix to a certain position

```
import pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx as dmtx
from PIL import Image

# Create the datamatrix
message = b'YourDataHere'
encoded = dmtx.encode(message)

# Convert the raw output to a PIL Image
datamatrix = Image.frombytes('RGB', (encoded.width, encoded.height), bytes(encoded.pixels))

# Convert to binary black and white
datamatrix = datamatrix.convert('1')

# Resize datamatrix to desired size
dm_size_px = (120, 120)
datamatrix = datamatrix.resize(dm_size_px, Image.NEAREST)

# Create white picture
picture_size_px = (250, 250)
picture = Image.new('RGB', picture_size_px, color='white')

# Position the datamatrix
barcode_position_px = (65, 65)
picture.paste(datamatrix, barcode_position_px)

# Save the image
picture.save("datamatrix.png")
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).